# How to use numpy.savetxt at the top of a file

Tags: python, numpy

My program writes several numpy arrays to a text file, then at the end I am trying to add the headers (another numpy array) to the top of the text file. I'm trying to either write over the first line (and just use a placeholder at the start of the file) or preferably insert the numpy array to the first line. The header function with numpy.savetxt won't work because it just writes the header over the last numpy array rather than the top of the file. I've also tried:

```
    Output.seek(0)
    np.savetxt(Output,nparr,delimiter=',',fmt='%s')
```

but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write some padding space initially and then overwrite it later.  There is no such operation as "insert content" in typical filesystems.

Then, to avoid `savetxt()` truncating your file, make it write to a `StringIO` object instead, which you can then copy into your file.  Like this:

```
txt = StringIO.StringIO() # Python 3: io.BytesIO()
np.savetxt(txt, nparr, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
Output.seek(0)
Output.write(txt.getvalue())
```

This assumes `Output` is a file object opened in a suitable mode.