# python3-numpy: Write header only if file is new with numpy savetxt

Tags: python, numpy, save

I am appending lines to an output file several times using numpy.savetxt similar to the mwe below. However, I would like to only write the header to the file once, i.e., if it didn't exist before. Other than checking every time I'm appending to the file if it already exists or not, is there a simpler way to achieve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

def write(array):
    with open('test.dat', 'ab') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, array, header='test header')

write([1, 2, 3])
write([4, 5, 6])
```

Output (test.dat):

```
# test header
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00
# test header
4.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00
```

Instead of this output, I would like only one header line at the top of the file.

Comment: Adding a file exists test to your function should be cheap enough.  It may be possible to check the file position after opening, but that doesn't save any code.

Comment: I'm not worried about saving code, I somehow thought there would be a better way to check that than doing an os.path.exists test or something. I would have to use f.tell() method to check the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import os

def write(array):
    header = '' # set empty header
    if not os.path.isfile('test.dat'): # checks if the file exists
        header = 'Test header' # if it doesn't then add the header
    with open('test.dat', 'ab') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, array, header=header)

write([1, 2, 3])
write([4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: That is what I wanted to avoid, but if it is as cheap as @hpaulj suggests, this is what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to check if the file exists each time you write to the file, you could adopt a workaround:
Whenever you write to the file, **do not* write the header at all. Only when you're done with *all* your write operations, insert the header at the beginning of the file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045075/12983399) is a SO answer explaining how to.